# Redis Combined Keys and Memory Usage command

Tags: redis

Redis 4.0
Keys Command can list all required pattern keys
Memory Usage [key] can return the key memory
How to use them together to get sum of the used memory for that pattern keys

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to implement that logic using any language you're most comfortable with. In pseudo code:

1. Get all key names using `KEYS`
2. For each key, get its `MEMORY USAGE`
3. Sum up the numbers

Note: don't use `KEYS` in production, use `SCAN`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Itamar pointed out, do not use `keys <pattern>` on production as this command does a complete scan on all the keys in the redis server. This query will degrade the redis performance and almost all of the redis queries will take considerate amount of time (as redis is a single threaded application). 
The thing you want to achieve can be achieved via creating a `Lua script`. Though I would recommend not to use custom solutions, there exists dashboards (like zabbix) for monitoring redis and memory usage.